# JavaScript - Object property as a function result like Array.length

Tags: javascript, object

I want to create property work as a result of function, like Array.length or VideoElement.currentTime.
But I don't want to use it like function call when the object is used.

For example:

```
var obj = {
   now : /* ??? */
}


console.log(obj.now)
Result : 2020-04-07 10:03:21

// 1 hours later
console.log(obj.now)
Result : 2020-04-07 11:03:21

// I don't want to implement like below:
console.log( obj.now() )
```

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it into a getter instead of a normal function:

```js
const obj = {
  get now() {
    return new Date().toString();
  }
};

console.log(obj.now);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(obj.now);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [object getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```js
const obj = {
  get now() {
    return Date.now()
  }
}

console.log(obj.now)
// logs: 15870XXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the function result and then use:

```
Object.defineProperty()
```

I would need a little more on what you're trying to do.

[mozilla doc I referenced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)